# Correct syntax for calling a stored procedure with parameters from within another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having difficulty establishing the correct syntax for calling a stored procedure within a stored procedure. I thought this syntax was correct:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[newProc](
    @param1 varchar(50),
    @param2 nvarchar(2000),
    @param3 int,
    @param4 int,
    @param5 int,
    @param6 int
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    EXEC [dbo].[externProc1] @param1, @param2;
    GO

    EXEC [dbo].[externProc2] @param3, @param4;
    GO

    EXEC [dbo].[insertProc3] @param5, @param6;
    GO

END
GO
```

But when I try this, I keep getting 
"Incorrect syntax near ';'  Must declare the scalar variable @param3.
Must declare the scalar variable @param5."

What is the correct syntax for calling a stored procedure with parameters from within another stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GO` keyword in T-SQL states that a block of t-sql statements ends and executes that block. This means that a variable defined in one block is not longer "in scope" for a statement occurring after that block has been ended/executed with `GO`.

GO is not actually a transact sql statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(v=sql.105).aspx

> Users must follow the rules for batches. For example, any execution of
>   a stored procedure after the first statement in a batch must include
>   the EXECUTE keyword. The scope of local (user-defined) variables is
>   limited to a batch, **and cannot be referenced after a GO command**.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I fixed it. Will give you the check once the time limit is up. If there is just a single GO at the end, will the preceding statements still execute synchronously? I.E. is there a reason not to just use a single GO at the end?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the the single GO at the end is not needed, especially when executing from within management studio.

Comment: GO is not a T-SQL statement period, it's just a helper for the MS Analyzer/Management Studio tools, so you CAN'T use it in a stored procedure